# React-Native build apk components doesn't run on device

Tags: android, apk, react-native

I have problem with some components when I build apk file. For example image not showing and button not working.

This is on virtual device and everything is okay and working:

[image]

And this is on physical device:

[image]

Comment: which commands you are using for building apk?

Comment: https://dev.to/nitish173/how-to-generate-a-debug-apk-in-react-native-1gdg

Comment: have you run the step 1 command?

Comment: Yes, couple of times I tried, but nothing happened

Comment: I only delete the drawable folders witch are created after that command because of the duplicated errors